# Circuitikz bipole label error

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I am trying to compile this circuit:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz} \draw
 (0,0) to[V=1<\volt>] (0,2)
 { to[R=1<\ohm>, color=red] (2,2) }
 to[C=1<\farad>] (2,0) -- (0,0) ;
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

But then I recive this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfk@/tikz/circuitikz/bipole/voltage/label/name ...
                                                  >
l.6  (0,0) to[V=1<\volt>] (0,2)
```

I copied this example verbatim from the manual (page 53, version 0.8.3). I compiled this using Tikz version 3.0.0 and circuitikz 0.3.0.

The circuitikz is completely outdated (running Debian Jessie) but I cannot dist-upgrade this system without breaking other things.

I downloaded circuitikzgit.sty from GitHub and placed it in the current working directory. Changed to

```
\usepackage{circuitikzgit}
```

but the problem remains exactly the same. The log file reports the inclusion of the new circuitikzgit.

As far as I can see, the only requirement for circuitikz is Tikz >= 3.0. Which it is. On this machine I have no other problems with Tikz and I am using features which are only available in Tikz 3.0.

I am not sure whether this is a version problem or something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the `siunitx` package. I suspected this because the units shown in the `CircuiTikZ` documentation are awfully similar to `siunitx`'s: `\kilo\ohm`.

Section 1.5 of (my version) of the documentation says:

**1.5 Requirements**

- Ti*k*Z, version ≥ 2;
- xstring, not older than 2009/03/13;
- siunitx, if using siunitx option.

and later it says:

• siunitx: integrates with SIunitx package. If labels, currents or voltages are
of the form `#1<#2>` then what is shown is actually `\SI{#1}{#2}`;

Comment: This was the fastest answer ever I have seen on tex.stackexchange. The voltage source now compiles correctly, but the next error is in the resistor. I'll have to post a new question with a new mwe for that.